# How get results only if the endDate NOT greater than today

Tags: mysql

I need only the ids where the endDate is not greater than today
or all endDates of the id are expired

table 1 t1

```
id | 
---
1
2
3
4
```

table 2 t2

```
id | t1_id | endDate
-----------------------
1  |   2   | 2019-01-01
2  |   3   | 2019-01-01
3  |   3   | 2020-01-01
4  |   3   | 2025-01-01
```

Query

```
SELECT t1.id ,t2.endDate 
FROM table_1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
WHERE NOT(t2.endDate > CURDATE())
AND ???
```

I need this result:

```
t1.id | t2.endDate
-----------------------
2     | 2019-01-01
```

Comment: It is unclear when "all endDates of the id are expired"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.endDate 
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM table_2 t
  WHERE t.t1_id = t2.t1_id AND t.endDate > CURDATE()
)
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29c161/3)

Comment: @Luke Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.